# スマホアプリ内でのPDFファイル出力方法

Tags: android, ios, monaca, pdf

お世話になります。

ただいまmonacaでスマホアプリを開発しています。
「YES」「NO」で答えるフローチャートのアプリですが、結果を出力した後、その結果と問題の答えを合わせてPDF化し、メールソフトを起動させて添付したいと思います。

問題とその答え、結果をメールソフト本文上に表示してメール送信することはできたのですが、できればこれらをPDFにしたいのです。どのような方法があるか教えてください。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 要件は「端末内でPDFを生成する」でしょうか？それとも「サーバー側でPDFを作成してもよい」でしょうか？

Comment: 早々にありがとうございます。

端末内での生成です。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

jsPDFというライブラリを発見しました。
https://parall.ax/products/jspdf

`text()`や、`addImage()`といったメソッドを利用して、簡単にテキストや画像を追加することが出来るようです。

しかし、日本語を使うと文字化けしてしまうようです。

[コチラ](http://devlog.mitsugeek.net/entry/2014/08/21/javascript%E3%81%A7PDF%E5%87%BA%E5%8A%9B%EF%BC%88%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E8%A1%A8%E7%A4%BA%EF%BC%89)では、canvasにテキストを描画することで日本語の出力を強制的に行っているようですが、あまり美しい方法ではありませんね。

Comment: ありがとうございます。試してみます。日本語出力がきちんとできるものがあるとありがたいですね。